# Чем отличается код формата "%i" от "%d" в scanf()

Tags: c++

Посмотрел на [этой странице](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/scanf) про процедуру scanf() из c++. В таблице указано, что код спецификатора формата для scanf() "%d" - считать десятичное число целого типа. Тоже самое указано про "%i".
Так вот, вопрос: в чем же их отличие?

**UPD:** Тоже самое я хотел бы узнать и про коды формата для чисел с плавающей точкой

Comment: %i помимо того же, что и %d обрабатывает как 16-ти и 8-меричные числа, начинающиеся с 0x и 0 соотв-но

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` - ожидает на входе строку с целым числом в десятичной системе счисления
`i` - ожидает на входе строку с целым числом в десятичной, восьмеричной (начинается с `0`) или шестнадцатиричной (`0x`) системе счисления
`f, e, g` - вещественное число, разницы между спецификаторами преобразования нет

Функции `scanf` и `printf` рассматриваются практически в любом справочнике по C/C++. Например:

- Харбисон, Стил. Язык программирования C. - М.: ООО "Бином-Пресс", 2004
- [Лишнер, C++. Справочник](http://www.piter.com/collection/starye-tovary/product/c-spravochnik)

Answer (score 6):

Если используется в семействе `scanf`, тогда `d` эквивалентен вызову [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) с основанием(системой счисления) `10`, а `i` эквивалентен вызову `strtol` с основанием `0`(что означает попробуй сам определи систему счисления)

Если используется в семействе `printf`, тогда между `d` и `i` нет никакого отличия.
Из стандарта C11:

> **d,i** The int argument is converted to signed decimal in the style
>   [-]dddd. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to
>   appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer
>   digits, it is expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1.
>   The result of converting a zero value with a precision of zero is no
>   characters.

Больше информации, по поводу различных форматов можно найти [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: вопрос был про scanf, отличия есть

Comment: @kroder, спасибо. Я поторопился

Comment: Про scanf хорошо бы в первую часть ответа перенести.

Comment: @alexolut, согласен, исправил\